# What is causing my program to display the wrong images?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gpbx1.Enter

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk20.CheckedChanged

    End Sub


    Dim Age As Integer
    Dim Gender As String
    Dim Male As String
    Dim Female As String
    Dim child As String
    Dim teen As String
    Dim adult As String
    Dim agerange As String
    Dim TeenMan As String
    Dim teengirl As String
    Dim childgirl As String
    Dim childboy As String
    Dim adultman As String
    Dim adultgirl As String
    Dim agegen As String

    Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk40.CheckedChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox4_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk60.CheckedChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox9_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.Enter

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Age = TextBox1.Text()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox6_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk90.CheckedChanged

    End Sub
    Function determineage()
        Age = Int(TextBox1.Text)
        Return True

    End Function
    Function getgender()
        If CheckBox7.Checked = True Then
            Gender = Male

        ElseIf CheckBox8.Checked = True Then
            Gender = Female

        ElseIf CheckBox7.Checked = False And CheckBox8.Checked = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a gender")
        End If
        Return True
    End Function
    Function determineagerange()
        If 20 < Age < 200 Then
            agerange = adult

        ElseIf 10 < Age < 20 Then
            agerange = teen

        ElseIf 10 < Age < 0 Then
            agerange = child

        End If
        Return True
    End Function
    Function determineagegender()
        If agerange = adult And Gender = Male Then
            agegen = adultman

        ElseIf agerange = adult And Gender = Female Then
            agegen = adultgirl

        ElseIf agerange = teen And Gender = Male Then
            agegen = TeenMan

        ElseIf agerange = teen And Gender = Female Then
            agegen = teengirl

        ElseIf agerange = child And Gender = Male Then
            agegen = childboy

        ElseIf agerange = child And Gender = Female Then
            agegen = childgirl


        End If
        Return True
    End Function

    Function Temperature()
        If chk20.Checked = True And agegen = TeenMan Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Teen\20.jpg")
        ElseIf chk40.Checked = True And agegen = TeenMan Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Teen\40.jpg")
        ElseIf chk50.Checked = True And agegen = TeenMan Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Teen\50.jpg")
        ElseIf chk60.Checked = True And agegen = TeenMan Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Teen\60.jpg")
        ElseIf chk80.Checked = True And agegen = TeenMan Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Teen\80.jpg")
        ElseIf chk90.Checked = True And agegen = TeenMan Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Teen\90.jpg")

        End If

        If chk20.Checked = True And agegen = adultman Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Adult\20.jpg")
        ElseIf chk40.Checked = True And agegen = adultman Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Adult\40.jpg")
        ElseIf chk50.Checked = True And agegen = adultman Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Adult\50.jpg")
        ElseIf chk60.Checked = True And agegen = adultman Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Adult\60.jpg")
        ElseIf chk80.Checked = True And agegen = adultman Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Adult\80.jpg")
        ElseIf chk90.Checked = True And agegen = adultman Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Adult\90.jpg")

        End If


        If chk20.Checked = True And agegen = childboy Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Child\20.jpg")
        ElseIf chk40.Checked = True And agegen = childboy Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Child\40.jpg")
        ElseIf chk50.Checked = True And agegen = childboy Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Child\50.jpg")
        ElseIf chk60.Checked = True And agegen = childboy Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Child\60.jpg")
        ElseIf chk80.Checked = True And agegen = childboy Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Child\80].jpg")
        ElseIf chk90.Checked = True And agegen = childboy Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\MALE\Child\90.jpg")

        End If
        Return True

    End Function

function temperaturegirl()

        If chk20.Checked = True And agegen = teengirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Teen\20.jpg")
        ElseIf chk40.Checked = True And agegen = teengirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Teen\40.jpg")
        ElseIf chk50.Checked = True And agegen = teengirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Teen\50.jpg")
        ElseIf chk60.Checked = True And agegen = teengirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Teen\60.jpg")
        ElseIf chk80.Checked = True And agegen = teengirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Teen\80.jpg")
        ElseIf chk90.Checked = True And agegen = teengirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Teen\90.jpg")

        End If

        If chk20.Checked = True And agegen = adultgirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Adult\20.jpg")
        ElseIf chk40.Checked = True And agegen = adultgirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Adult\30.jpg")
        ElseIf chk50.Checked = True And agegen = adultgirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Adult\50.jpg")
        ElseIf chk60.Checked = True And agegen = adultgirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Adult\60.jpg")
        ElseIf chk80.Checked = True And agegen = adultgirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Adult\70.jpg")
        ElseIf chk90.Checked = True And agegen = adultgirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Adult\90.jpg")

        End If


        If chk20.Checked = True And agegen = childgirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Child\20.jpg")
        ElseIf chk40.Checked = True And agegen = childgirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Child\40.jpg")
        ElseIf chk50.Checked = True And agegen = childgirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Child\50.jpg")
        ElseIf chk60.Checked = True And agegen = childgirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Child\60.jpg")
        ElseIf chk80.Checked = True And agegen = childgirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Child\80].jpg")
        ElseIf chk90.Checked = True And agegen = childgirl Then
            PictureBox1.Load("H:\AP  CSP\VB\FEMALE\Child\90.jpg")

        End If



        Return True
    End Function

    Private Sub btcalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btcalc.Click
        getgender()
        determineage()
        determineagerange()
        determineagegender()
        If Gender = Male Then
            Temperature()
        ElseIf Gender = Female Then
            temperaturegirl()
        End If



    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox5_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk80.CheckedChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox7_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox7.CheckedChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox8_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox8.CheckedChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

The point of the program is to display an image based on the the information provided by the user, however it only displays images of young boys for every input. The image is always right for the given temperature, however the age and gender are wrong.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details, here, as it's quite difficult to answer as it is.

Comment: What happens when you step through the code in the debugger?  You should be able to see the path the program is following and that will tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This code really is quite badly written but I won't go into that too much.

Your biggest problem is that you are creating a bunch of variables for everything, that are always empty.

`Gender`, `Male`, and `Female` are all created as string variables, with no value.

When you set `Gender = Male`, you are setting `Gender` to an empty string, because `Male` is an empty string. You do the same thing when you set `Gender = Female`.

When it comes to your comparison, `If Gender = Male` always succeeds because you are comparing two empty strings.

You're better off only creating the `Gender` variable (Get rid of the `Male` & `Female` variables). Then set the value of this to the **string** "Male" or "Female":

```
Gender = "Male"
```

Then check the value against a string in your `If` statement:

```
If Gender = "Male" Then
```

Same issue for the age ranges.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I know it's poor, but I'm under time constraints and I'm a beginner with the language and programming in general. I fixed it by changing the variables! Thanks for your help!